# Two pubslisher for the same message type in Rebus

Tags: rebus

Is it possible to have two publishers for the same Message Type and multiple subscribers subscribing to the one they want?If yes how can I achieve it?Please suggest.

Comment: I tried with two publishers and looks like even if I run publisher 1 and try to publish something it doesn't publish. But for Publisher 2 it publishes the messages crrectly on its input queue. What could be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you should model your system so that one particular endpoint "owns" any given event type and thus would be the one to publish it.

There nothing that technically prevents you from publishing the same event types from multiple endpoints, though, but I would recomment that they share the subscription storage in that case - e.g. in a SQL Server (works well with Express editions as well) somewhere.

This way, client just need to map the event type to any arbitrary endpoint out of the ones that are capable of publishing it, so that when they `bus.Subscribe<SomeEvent>()`, all the publishers will get that subscriber when they `bus.Publish(new SomeEvent { ... })`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The main issue is - we want to have certain subscribers who need to subscribe to only certain publishers and not all.So ideally in the scenario you described above they will receive the message from the other publishers too.

Comment: By 'one particular endpoint' owning event types, do you mean applications/modules? Or can multiple applications publish the same event type to the same endpoint/queue, to be picked up by a single consumer application?

Comment: You can have as many publishers as you want if you share the subscription storage. With Rebus 2 (versions >= 0.90.0), you can even configure some of the subscription storages to be centralized, which removes the whole message ownership concept from pub/sub messaging